# PHP form not validating or sending due to if statements?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation

I'm trying to update a table on a page by having a user fill out a form that has been validated. For some reason, when I add the validation if statements the form does not do anything except refresh when the user clicks "add new". If I remove the if statements, the table is updated. What am I missing?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "db.php";

if ( isset ($_POST['url']) && isset ($_POST['email']) 
&& isset ($_POST['length']) && isset ($_POST['rating']) ) {

    //Reject empty form fields
    if (strlen($_POST['url']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['email']) <1 || strlen ($_POST['length']) <1 || strlen($_POST['rating']) < 1) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'All values are required';
    header('Location: add.php');
    return;
    } 

    //Reject urls that are not http or https
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    if (strpos($url,"http://") !== 0 && strpos($url, "https://") !== 0 ) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Error in input data';
    header('Location: add.php');
    return;
    }

    //Reject emails without '@' symbol
    if ( strpos($_POST['email'], "@") === false ) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Error in input data';
    header('Location: add.php');
    return;
    }

    //Reject track lengths or rating numbers that are too small
    if ( $_POST['length'] +0 < 1 || $_POST['rating'] +0 < 1 ) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Error in input data';
    header('Location: add.php');
    return;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO videos (url, email, length, rating) 
              VALUES (:url, :email, :length, :rating)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
            ':url' => $_POST ['url'],
            ':email' => $_POST ['email'],        
            ':length' => $_POST['length'],
            ':rating' => $_POST['rating']));
   $_SESSION['success'] = 'Record Added';
   header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
   return;

}

?>

<p>Add A New Video</p>
<form method="post">
<p>URL:
<input type="text" name="url"></p>
<p>Email:
<input type="text" name="email"></p>
<p>Length:
<input type="text" name="length"></p>
<p>Rating:
<input type="text" name="rating"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Add New"/>
<a href="index.php">Cancel</a></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you checked (printed) the values of the variables to see what they store?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your validation using strpos is prone to trouble. Try to use regular expressions like this:

```
if (! preg_match('/[^@\s]{3,}@([-a-z0-9]{2,}\.)+[a-z]{2,}/', $_POST['e_mail'])) { $_SESSION['error'] = 'Error in input data'; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made this change but it did not resolve my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

See if the code below works for you? I've slightly modified the condition for the *length* and *rating* fields, as well as the email field. Good luck!

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "db.php";

if ( isset ($_POST['url']) && isset ($_POST['email']) 
&& isset ($_POST['length']) && isset ($_POST['rating']) ) {

    //Reject empty form fields
    if (strlen($_POST['url']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['email']) < 1 || strlen ($_POST['length']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['rating']) < 1) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'All values are required';
        die(header('Location: add.php'));
    } 

    //Reject urls that are not http or https
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    if (strpos($url,"http://") !== 0 && strpos($url, "https://") !== 0 ) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Error in input data';
        die(header('Location: add.php'));
    }

    //Reject emails without '@' symbol
    if (FILTER_VAR($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Error in input data';
        die(header('Location: add.php'));
    }

    //Reject track lengths or rating numbers that are too small
    if ($_POST['length'] < 1 || $_POST['rating'] < 1 || $_POST['length'] > 1000 || $_POST['rating'] > 1000) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Error in input data';
        die(header('Location: add.php'));
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO videos (url, email, length, rating) 
              VALUES (:url, :email, :length, :rating)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
            ':url' => $_POST ['url'],
            ':email' => $_POST ['email'],        
            ':length' => $_POST['length'],
            ':rating' => $_POST['rating']));
   $_SESSION['success'] = 'Record Added';
   header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;

}

?>

<p>Add A New Video</p>
<form method="post">
<p>URL:
<input type="text" name="url"></p>
<p>Email:
<input type="text" name="email"></p>
<p>Length:
<input type="text" name="length"></p>
<p>Rating:
<input type="text" name="rating"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Add New"/>
<a href="index.php">Cancel</a></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Your code is reacting the same way that mine did :/ Refreshes the page but doesn't catch anything. If I comment out the validation if statements it allows me to input data and redirects to index.php.

Comment: @user3384487 why not just do nested if... else statements then? As in, one after another? Also, you need to add an *action=""* attribute to your form, with the value being the URL or page name that does the processing. In this case, since you're processing on the same page, you can leave the value blank.

Comment: @user3384487 I would use action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"